# Interpreting SSRS parameters

Tags: sql-server, oracle, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, business-intelligence

I'm making reports in visual studio for SSRS, I was wondering if I have a parameter which takes multiple values (which end up populating my table) if I could interpret these parameters. I would like to take the input from the user and perform some logic on it (in this case compare it to a string, if it matches then use this, if it doesn't match then use the original input from the user). The list of possible entries is too large to have the user select from a predefined list too.

So for example:

data set is: `select * from details where cust_nme in (:customers)`

Then the user can enter multiple values into customer. But sometimes the user might enter Mr Jackson instead of just Jackson and the database doesn't contain mr. So I need the report to interpret this as just Jackson.   (pretend we can't tell the user not to use prefix MR)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you want to change "MR ..." to "...", so you'll need to match "MR "

Go to: datasets->dataset properties->parameters tab

Set the parameter value to this expression:
=Split(Replace((join(Parameters!Name.Value, ",")), "MR ", ""), ",")

This expression will take an array of customers as input from the user, join them into one comma delimited string. It then replaces all "MR " with "". The final step is then to split it into an array again.

Beware that customer names can't contain commas.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
Customer_Name,
'Mr' + ' ' + Name AS Mr_Customer_Name
From Table
Where (Customer_Name in (@Customers)
OR Mr_Customer_Name in (@Customers))
```